# Differential equations strange 2 DOF systems

Tags: mechanical-engineering

I'm trying to find state-space representation of following `2DOF` systems.

[image]

I tried classic `Double pendulum equations` for it but I'm confused how to handle it. now I'm looking for any help and tip to solve it.

Comment: What exactly did you try? Please provide more information on what you tried so that someone will be able to help without explaining everything.